# Putting hyperlinks in source code

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio, is it possible to create hyperlinks inside source files that jump to a specific line of a file? I want to create a link to a specific line, like this:

```
// [[#DoStuff|Clicking here will take you to the method "doStuff."]]
//
//
//
//
// #DoStuff
//clicking the hyperlink should jump to the line above.
function doStuff(){

}
```

Is there any way to create hyperlinks in the comments that will jump to a specific method?

Comment: It looks like there's a plugin called HyperAddin that can do this: http://hyperaddin.codeplex.com/ Unfortunately, it looks like it's only available for Visual Studio 2005 and Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Not sure why you would need to hyperlink to a method when there so many navigation tools built into vs, is there a good reason for this requirement?

Comment: @Charleh It looks like it's already possible to [jump to a specific line using the CTRL+G shortcut](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/08/go-to-a-line-number-vstipedit0026.aspx). This should be useful enough.

Comment: There's also f12 and other navigation functions, are you talking about navigating from comments? Usually if there is a comment it's about some code which is contextually relevant and therefore you can use the right click menu to navigate to the required symbol

Comment: @Charleh I haven't noticed this feature before. How can you use the right-click menu to navigate to a specific symbol?

Comment: Right click on a method/type/variable and choose go to declaration or go to definition etc, should be in the right click context menu, won't work in comments though, only in code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28613/discussion-between-anderson-green-and-charleh)

Comment: I'm at the pub right now! Maybe later!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's [a Visual Studio plugin called HyperAddin that can do this](http://hyperaddin.codeplex.com). Unfortunately, it looks like it's only available for Visual Studio 2005 and Visual Studio 2008.